# Variable Adjacent & hypotenues

Tags: geometry

I need a formula that satisfies the following:
When the adjacent is 2.5 the hypotenuse must be 7.5
When the adjacent is 10 the hypotenuse must be 45
What is the formula to work out the hypotenuse from any value of the adjacent?

It's getting on for 30 year since college & I've forgotten a lot!

Comment: It's a part of a triangle?

Comment: @Simon1805 Use $cos{\theta} = a/h$

Answer (score 0):

If they are triangles,

For triangle 1: $\cos \theta = {2.5\over7.5} ={1\over3}$

For triangle 2: $\cos \theta = {10\over45} ={2\over9}$

Since $\cos \theta$ is constant for a certain triangle, plug in the value of the adjacent side and solve for the hypotenuse.

Comment: It actually represents two dissimilar triangles as the ratios on the RHS are nor the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that they are different triangles.

Comment: cosθ varies on the triangles produced.
So the answer will probably be (I think)
Hypotenuse  = vaj² + (vaj + f(vaj))²

Comment: Perhaps it would have been clearer if I had written:

Hypotenuse = adj² + (adj + f(adj))²


Where f(adj) is the ratio of the increase of the hypotenuse WRT the value of the adjacent

Comment: just these two values of $\cos \theta$ for the triangle will not be enough if we do not know how it varies.